# NSPredicate causes App to crash on typing in UISearchBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nspredicate

I believe I have narrowed it down to this code here:

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{

    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name contains[c] %@", searchText];
    NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithArray:users];
    NSLog(@"%@",array);
    searchResults = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
    NSLog(@"SR: %@",searchResults);
    searchResults = array;
}
```

I start with an NSMutableArray `users` and "convert" it to an array, creatively names `array`. From here I try to filter the array with Predicate. at this point `searchResults` becomes seemingly empty based on the `NSLog`.

What is going on here? Why is this crashing? If I ignore the Predicate function and give searchResults two objects in an array, regardless of what I type, the first two cells in `users` will appear. Everything else I try just makes the app crash.

When the app crashes I get the following, incredibly helpful (sarcasm) console log:

```
     *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<__NSCFString 0x165025b0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: 
this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key name.'
    *** First throw call stack:
    (0x28fdbc1f 0x36786c8b 0x28fdb929 0x29cbe5ab 0x29c25677 0x29c618c9 0x29c6148b 0x29c60477 0x29c60299 0x355fd 0x3582f 0x2c677be5 0x2c677b1f 0x2c4cbc2b 0x2c4cbbd1 0x2c4b6863 0x2c677909 0x2c4d5ab5 0x2c64798b 0x2c646f29 0x2c677741 0x2c646d77 0x2c7df457 0x2c7df1ef 0x2c4c03cd 0x29cead6f 0x28fa2377 0x28fa1787 0x28f9fded 0x28eee211 0x28eee023 0x302e70a9 0x2c4fa1d1 0x21ac5 0x36d06aaf)
    libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
    (lldb)
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The message is pretty clear - your array contains `NSString` objects, which don't have a property `name`, but your predicate specifies that you want to compare the value of the `name` property.

you probably want

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[c] %@", searchText];
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you so much. I read through Apple's Predicate docs and believe it or not this wasn't as obvious as it seems haha. I really appreciate it, thanks man.